# How to route differently, with default route in place?

Tags: routing, cisco, route

I have a setup as below:

PC A --> Microtik --> C3750 --> ISP router

Both Microtik & C3750 is configured with 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 **ISP IP** static route.
This means that traffic from **PC A** will go to microtik, then C3750 and finally to **ISP IP** before going to destination.

My question is: 
If i have a new device connecting to C3750, how do i configure on microtik and C3750 to ensure that **PC A** reaches the new device via C3750?

If you need more information, do let me know.
Appreciate the kind comments.
Thanks!

**EDIT_1**: From **C3750**, i can reach the new device. But i'm still unable to reach the new device from **PC A** or **Microtik.**

Answer (score 0):

Post your configuration.

You are most likely missing a return route or a firewall rule to allow communications to between the 2 devices..

PC_A is behind your Mirotik which most likely using a basic firewall to protect it from any traffic that is deemed as "external" aka the internet.